# UTF8 to latin1_swedish_ci

Tags: php, character-encoding

There are a lot of topics about latin1_swedisch_ci to utf8 conversion. But what about the other way around? I'm dealing for quite a long time with this problem and I haven't found a solution so far. Since I don't know what else is accessing this database, I don't want to change the character encoding of the table.

I have in the table a column which is formatted in latin1_swedisch_ci. Now I have to write queries in php. This database contains German and French names, meaning that I have characters like ö,ä,ô and so on. How can I do that?

As an example if I want to query the name 'Bürki', then I have to write something like $name='BÃ¼rki'. Is there a proper way to convert it to latin1_swedisch_ci without using string replacement for those special characters?

Comment: First of all, do you really want to store your text encoded in Latin1? That means you can only store the 256 possible characters defined in the Latin1 encoding. No other foreign characters are possible to be stored. And "BÃ¼rki" just means that you have an encoding mismatch somewhere, most likely you're trying to store UTF-8 encoded data in a database that expects Latin1. You should rather fix this mismatch.

Comment: I ran a script which should have convert latin1_swedish_ci columns to UTF8. However, all variables which contained a special like 'Bürki' were converted to 'B' (or Brühlmann to 'Br')...

Comment: @mkn that happens when iconv (or mysql) encounter a character that is invalid in the current encoding.

Answer (score 5):

[`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv) will convert strings from one encoding to the other.

The encodings that are of interest to you are `utf-8` and `iso-8859-1` - the latter is equivalent with `latin1`.

The "swedish", "german" etc. localizations affect issues like sorting only, the character encoding is always the same.

PS.

> then I have to write something like $name='BÃ¼rki'.

If you encode your source file as UTF-8, you can write `Bürki` directly. (You would then have to convert that string into `iso-8859-1`)

Comment: if I do $name =  iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1","Bär"); then $name is being set to 'B' hmm...

Comment: @mkn then you are not encoding the source file as UTF-8. See above.

Comment: @mkn then that shouldn't happen. Are you 1000% sure?

Comment: I opened the source file in TextWrangler and at the bottom it says UTF-8. Also my Textmate editor saves all files with UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pekka, however, I would try to use the [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)() function instead because it is possible that iconv is not installed...

Iconv, however, is more powerful - it can do transliteration for an example. But for this purpose I believe [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)() is enough.