# Using accented characterse in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my input texts from forms. When the user enters in a text form input something like "test ăĂșșțîâ" CodeIgniter query saves to the database after getting post input something like "test ???????".
I have 2 variants:
1. first is to convert "ăâîșț" and "ĂÂÎȘȚ" TO "aaist" and "AAIST".
2. to find a method to save accented characters in DB without saving like "????"

I'm already using html_purify and strip_tags to input.
Does someone have some ideas?

Here is my code to GET input form:

```
strip_tags(html_purify($this->input->post("postandclose", true)));
```

Comment: Your database table should be utf8. Is it?

Comment: is latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: Try making that utf8.

Comment: what is your html charset meta

Comment: @umefarooq        <meta name content="utf-8">

Comment: @MuhammadUmair i can't change this in db because it's connected to multiple things and i can cause some problems

Comment: you are sending utf8 format data from HTML to your database, best way to convert your table to utf8 first take backup of table or make copy of your table with data than convert charset of table also charset of table columns too. check here 2nd answer may be solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345264/utf8-to-latin1-swedish-ci

Comment: It's already discussed in stackoverflow, here's another one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854446/save-accents-in-mysql-database